# Looping in assembly language

Tags: c#, loops, assembly, x86

how do I translate this C# code in assembly using loops and/or jumps

```
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 15;

        while (count != 0)
        {
            if (count % 2 != 0)
                sum = sum + count;
            count--;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: The best place to start is study the instruction set for desired platform and then use an appropriate assembler to generate code.

Comment: I sort of wonder what is puzzling you about this, because this can be translated almost 1:1 to x86 ASM instructions (I'm assuming x86, as you didn't specify target CPU), so is it just lack of confidence to try to do it, or you didn't even see the instruction set at all (try to find 80286 or 80386 set first, it contains all the basic instructions, no need to learn whole modern x86 set with all the extended stuff like SSE or floating point at the beginning). Would you try at least something, and describe what you did, it would be maybe easier to see where is the problem, and what to suggest...

Comment: Another kind of answer to this question is: write it as valid C++ (just remove Console) and compile with "to assembly" switch. C/C++ compilers are pretty good at producing assembly.

Comment: There's no one way to output text in assembly language; it depends on your target platform (which you didn't specify).

Answer (score 1):

a "while" is usually

```
L_repeat:
    compare while_condition
    jumpIfFalse L_exit

    ... loop body ...

    jump L_repeat
L_exit:
```

also for an if, you have to invert the condition:

```
compare if_condition
jumpIfFalse L_skip

 ... inside if

L_skip:
```

then you need to Registers, one to hold your count, one for the sum, and come out with something like this:

```
mov Rsum,0
mov Rcount,15

L_repeat:
   cmp Rcount,0
   jz L_exit          ; jump if not (Rcount != 0) gets jump if Rcount==0
       mov Rtemp, Rcount
       and Rtemp, 1
       jz L_skip
       add Rsum, Rcount
    L_skip:
       dec Rcount
       jmp L_repeat
l_exit:
```